# Binding not setted with XamlWriter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have my class:

```
public class CustomCell
{
    public string BindingData
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(BindingDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BindingDataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BindingData", typeof(string), typeof(CustomCell));
}
```

I set a binding with BindingDataProperty

```
CustomCell cell = new CustomCell();
cell.SetBinding(CustomCell.BindingDataProperty, new Binding("source"));
```

And now I want to get the XAML equivalent string using `XamlWriter`:

```
string xaml = XamlWriter.Save(cell);
```

But in the `xaml` string `BindingData` is `{x:Null}` and no any binding is done.

Why? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [Serialization Limitation of XamlWriter.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx)

See the MSDN documentation:

> Common references to objects made by various markup extension formats,
>   such as StaticResource or **Binding**, will be dereferenced by the
>   serialization process.  These were already dereferenced at the time
>   that in-memory objects were created by the application runtime, and
>   the Save logic does not revisit the original XAML to restore such
>   references to the serialized output. This potentially freezes any
>   databound or resource obtained value to be the value last used by the
>   run-time representation, with only limited or indirect ability to
>   distinguish such a value from any other value set locally. Images are
>   also serialized as object references to images as they exist in the
>   project, rather than as original source references, losing whatever
>   filename or URI was originally referenced. Even resources declared
>   within the same page are seen serialized into the point where they
>   were referenced, rather than being preserved as a key of a resource
>   collection.

Comment: How microsoftly this is! I have been researching for two days now...