# Setting source to resource image inside project

Tags: c#, flowdocument

I samples of FlowDocument in C# show images pointing to a location on disk in the xaml file. If I want to point source to image inside program as resource or how do i set the source setting then? I ship my program flowdocument as part of the program and I cant install images on disk. I want them as resource inside the program.

```
  <InlineUIContainer >
      <Image Margin="2,0" Width="50" Source="C:\sample.jpg" ></Image>
  </InlineUIContainer>
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557891/xaml-wpf-how-to-add-inline-background-image-on-flowdocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set image's Build action to Resource and use following code:

```
    <InlineUIContainer >
        <Image Margin="2,0" Width="50" Source="pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;Images/sample.jpg"></Image>
    </InlineUIContainer>
```

sample.jpg must be in folder "Images" in your project in this example.

Comment: <InlineUIContainer>
            <Image Margin="2,0" Width="186" Source="pack://application:,,,/sample.jpg" Height="77"></Image>
          </InlineUIContainer> This work for me... The ide work.